# I want to use recyclerView, but the view doesn't have any values. kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

```
class SummonerInfoActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var participantAdapter: ParticipantAdapter

    private val recycler: RecyclerView by lazy {
        findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val Summoner = intent.getParcelableExtra<SummonerDTO>("SummonerDTO")
        Log.e("Info","${Summoner}")

   

        val retrofit2 = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://asia.api.riotgames.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
      
        lolAPIForMatch = retrofit2.create(lolAPIService::class.java)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_summoner_info)

        participantAdapter = ParticipantAdapter()
        recycler.adapter = participantAdapter
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SummonerInfoActivity)

        getMatchIdBypuuid(Summoner?.puuId.orEmpty(),Summoner?.summonerName.orEmpty())
   
    }

    private fun getMatchIdBypuuid(puuid: String,summonerName: String){

        lolAPIForMatch.getMatchIdBypuuid(puuid, 0,20, API_KEY)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<List<String>> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<String>>,
                    response: Response<List<String>>
                ) {

                    if(response.isSuccessful.not()){
                     
                        return
                    }
                    response.body()?.let {
                        it.forEach {
                            searchMatchInfoByMatchID(it,summonerName)                  
                        }

                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<String>>, t: Throwable) {

                }

            })
    }
    private fun searchMatchInfoByMatchID(matchId: String,summonerName: String){
        lolAPIForMatch.getMatchInfoByMatchID(matchId, API_KEY)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<MatchDTO>{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<MatchDTO>, response: Response<MatchDTO>) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful.not()){
                        return
                    }

                    response.body()?.let {

                  
                        it.info.participants.filter {
                            it.summonerName == "${summonerName}"
                        }.forEach {
                           
                            participantAdapter.participants.add(it)
                        }

                    }

                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<MatchDTO>, t: Throwable) {

                }

            })

    }
}

class ParticipantAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ParticipantAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    var participants = mutableListOf<ParticipantDTO>()
    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        fun bind(participant: ParticipantDTO){
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.kill).text = participant.kills.toString()
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.death).text = participant.deaths.toString()
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.assist).text = participant.assists.toString()
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ParticipantAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_match, parent, false))
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParticipantAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(participants[position])
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return participants.size
    }
}
```

`participantAdapter.participants.add(it)`
The command is `searchMatchInfoByMatchID`
In the function, you can check that the value is entered correctly, but
If you check in the onCreate function, the value is not assigned.
I want to use the recycler view by properly assigning a value

I tried to solve this problem, but my skills were not enough.

I desperately need the advice of seniors.

I would really appreciate it if you could show me a code sample if possible

Comment: Call `participantAdapter.notifyItemInserted(participantAdapter.participants.size)` ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int))) after you add an item.

Comment: wow!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! amazing

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!
If it wasn't for you I would
You would not have been able to complete this project.
thank you for your kindness